# cmake sybase ctlib build errors

Tags: makefile, cmake, sybase, centos7

- Centos 7
- cmake 3.6.1
- sybase-15.0.5
- gcc.4.9.2

Cmake generation is OK, but make is failed with this error:

```
/linopt/sybase-15.0-esd5/OCS-15_0/include/ctpublic.h:269:41: error: 'SQLDA' has not been declared
 extern CS_RETCODE CS_PUBLIC ct_dynsqlda PROTOTYPE((
```

from CMmakeLists:

```
find_package(Sybase 15.0.5 EXACT REQUIRED)
```

So ctpublic.h is included, but  where SQLDA is defined is not.

Adding this does not help:

target_include_directories(myApp
PUBLIC ${Sybase_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

**PostgreSql** 9.6.8 library is also used in my project.

**UPDATE:**
Just figured out that these 2 libraries have 2 same files "sqlda.h".
How it can be resolved?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution - used PostgreSQL library version 10.4 instead of 9.6.8 and errors are gone. Enjoy.